# Are Cartesian coordinates considered to be curvilinear coordinates?

Tags: geometry, terminology, coordinate-systems

In the wikipedia page on [curvilinear coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curvilinear_coordinates) it is said:

"Well-known examples of curvilinear coordinate systems in three-dimensional Euclidean space (R^3) are Cartesian, cylindrical and spherical polar coordinates."

Is this generally accepted as correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.  "Curvilinear" means that the coordinate lines are *allowed* to be more general curves, but they can also just be straight lines.